# Filter Data on basis of daily, weekly or monthly in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Say I have mongodb schema :

**imageSchema.js:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const imageRead = mongoose.Schema({
    image_id: { type: String },
    imageRead: { type: String, default: 'READ' },
    readOn: { type: Date }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('image-read', imageRead, 'image-read');
```

Route to call api:

**someApi.js:**

```
//import **someController.js**
app.get('/detail/', image-details);
```

Controller:

**someController.js:**

```
exports.image-details = async (req, res) => {

    let monthly = new Date();

    const imageRead = await imageSchema.aggregate([{ $match: { image_id: imageId } }, 
    { $match: { imageRead: { $nin: ["UNREAD"] } } }, { $project: { month: { $month: "$readOn" } } }, 
    { $match: { month: monthly.getMonth() + 1 } }, { $count: 'total' }]).exec();
    console.log(imageRead) //gives the count of total image read per month
})
```

I tried filtering on basis of month which is successfully doing so.....but I'm struggling with how to filter on basis of daily and weekly count.

Please let me know if any more details is required.